# Summing Variances/ Meaning of np.cov using Python/Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, covariance, variance

Using Python:

So I have a DataFrame called File where I want to find the overall variance of one of its columns 'Prices'.

For the variance formula, I understand you have to include the covariance.

I read that np.cov will yield a covariance matrix. However when I use it, I don't get a matrix (or so I think)

My code

```
np.cov(File['Prices'])
```

gives me

```
 array(2118322.0106797763)
```

Does this answer then compute the following function: Var(All prices) = Var(price 1) + .....+ Var(Price N) + 2[Cov(X1,X2) + .....+Cov(N-1,N)]

So then the 2118322 is actually the summation of the variances? I was expecting to get a matrix not what I actually got.

Comment: You shouldn't call your variable `File`, it's a reserved keyword in python. Call it `my_file` if you must. Is your dataframe a `pandas` dataframe? What is the shape of the data passed to `np.cov`?

Comment: I actually called it Catalog in the actual code. Good call though!

Comment: It is a pandas df. The shape of the data is a series with about 100,000 values so Catalog['Price'] lists just all of the prices in a catalog

Answer (score 3):

You're just passing in a single sequence, so you're getting a single variance.

Basically, you're doing something like:

```
np.cov([3.4, 5.6, ..., 9.8, 4.5])
```

...which just yields the variance of the sequence.

If you want a covariance matrix describing the relationship between multiple variables, you'll need to pass in a 2D array.  By default, `numpy.cov` expects an `numdimensions x numsamples` array.  (This can be changed either by using `rowvar=False` or by just passing in the transpose of the data.)

Basically, something like this:

```
import numpy as np

# Generate two 100-sample sequences
data = np.random.random((2, 100))

print np.cov(data)
```

Or with a `pandas` dataframe, just call the `cov` method:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Generate two 100-sample sequences
x, y = np.random.random((2, 100))
data = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, y=y))

# Similarly, we could have done "np.cov(data.T)", though that would yield 
# an array instead of a dataframe
print data.cov()
```